# displaying list inline as text within an MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of items in ViewModel. For every item in the list, display as a list. Eg.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
  <li><a href="link">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DisplayName)</a>
}
```

Which is displayed as:

- Item 1
- item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

But how do I display it so that it has an "and" before the last item, and a comma after each one. Like this:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 and Item 4.
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pure CSS solution to do that

```css
ul.cs-list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.cs-list li::after {
  content: ',';
}

ul.cs-list li:last-child::after {
  content: '.';
}

ul.cs-list li:nth-last-child(2)::after {
  content: 'and';
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cs-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. It almost worked, except there is no "and" on the last item. Bare in mind that it is not a static list. It is a list displaying a list item for each item within a list()
@foreach (item in Model.Items) { <li> </li>}

Comment: @user6950100 It should include 'and' before last item. Try to click on the "Run Code Snippet" button.

Comment: Sorry, yes it did I just spelt the class wrong in that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use and index variable inside the foreach (initialize it with 0 at first) and increment it with every loop, add an if statement based on it , comparing it with the Model.Items.Count-1 will give you the info if it's previous to last one or not.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired output I have used a counter variable that will be used to consider the last element (which should be appended with 'and' word).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Create List of Model
        var lst = new List<Model>();

        //Insert Elements into List
        lst.Add(new Model{ ID = 1, Name = "ABC"});
        lst.Add(new Model{ ID = 2, Name = "DEF"});
        lst.Add(new Model{ ID = 3, Name = "GHI"});
        lst.Add(new Model{ ID = 4, Name = "JKL"});
        lst.Add(new Model{ ID = 5, Name = "MNO"});

        //Actual Logic to get proper output
        int count = 0;
        string output = @"";
        foreach(var currentModel in lst){

        if(count == lst.Count - 1){
            output = output + "and " + "<a href='link'>" + currentModel.Name + "</a>";
        }
        else{
            output = output + "<a href='link'>" + currentModel.Name + "</a>" + ", ";
        }
        count ++;
    }
        ViewBag.Links = output; //Now you can use it on View
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}

public class Model{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```